# Quantum Mapping of a Generalized 2D XY Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, partition-function, bosons

I have been reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01475), which discusses the deconfinement transition in the 2D generalized XY model. The classical Hamiltonian is given by the following. See page 2 of the paper.

$$
H = - J\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle}\bigg[(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_i - \theta_j \big) + \Delta \cos\big(2\theta_i - 2\theta_j \big) \bigg]
$$

Directly beneath this equation the paper mentions that

> > In an associated quantum chain, the two terms ... correspond respectively
> > to the hopping of single bosons and of boson pairs.

In order to see what the corresponding quantum model is, I considered the partition function of the classical system for small $K$. We set $-\beta J$ to $K$.

For a 2D square lattice with periodic boundary conditions on the rows and columns, the above Hamiltonian can be written as the following. Note that $\theta_{(i,j)}$ is the rotor at the $i$-th column of the $j$-th row

$$
-\beta H = K \sum_\text{row j} \sum_\text{site i in j}\bigg[(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) + (1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i,j+1)} \big) + \Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) + \Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i,j+1)} \big) \bigg]
$$

Therefore

$$
e^{-\beta H } = \prod_i \prod_j e^{K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i+1,j)} \big)} e^{K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)} e^{K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i+1,j)} \big)} e^{K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)}
$$
$$
e^{-\beta H }\approx \prod_i \prod_j \big(1 + K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) \big)\big(1 + K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)\big)\big(1 + K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i+1,j)} \big)\big)\big(1 +  K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)\big)
$$
$$
e^{-\beta H }\approx \prod_i \prod_j \bigg[ 1 + K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i+1,j)} \big)  +  K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i,j+1)} \big) + K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) + K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)\bigg]
$$
$$
e^{-\beta H }\approx 1 + \sum_\text{row j} \sum_\text{site i in j} K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) + \sum_\text{row j} \sum_\text{site i in j}K(1 - \Delta)\cos\big(\theta_{(i,j)} - \theta_{(i,j+1)} \big) + \sum_\text{row j} \sum_\text{site i in j}K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i+1,j)} \big) + \sum_\text{row j} \sum_\text{site i in j} K\Delta\cos\big(2\theta_{(i,j)} - 2\theta_{(i,j+1)} \big)
$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. How does the quantum mapping work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're complicating things

in the semiclassical expansion, the quantum annihilation and creation operators become

$\hat{a}=\sqrt{n}e^{i\theta}$, $\hat{a}^\dagger=\sqrt{n}e^{-i\theta}$

Single-photon hopping means terms like $\hat{a_i}^\dagger\hat{a_j}+h.c.$ and two-photon hopping ${\hat{a_i}^\dagger}^2\hat{a_j}^2+h.c.$ .
Substitute the above and assume $n$ to be constant